# C++ Save a Struct String into A Text File

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

In my program, I save high scores along with a time in minutes and seconds. In my code, I currently store this as two `int`s in a struct called `highscore`. However, this is a little tedious when it comes to formatting when I display the output. I want to display the times as `12:02` not `12:2`. I have a variable already made called string clock throughout my game, it is already formatted with the colon, all I want to do is add that inside my text file.

How can I refactor my code to have a single variable for the timestamp, which will be correctly formatted? I want to be able to write my data into the file by directly calling the structure.

```
// Used for Highscores
struct highscore
{
    char name[10]; 
    int zombiesKilled; 

    // I would like these to be a single variable        
    int clockMin;
    int clockSec;

    char Date[10];
}; 

// I write the data like this:
highscore data;
// ...
data[playerScore].clockMin = clockData.minutes;
data[playerScore].clockSec = clockData.seconds;

streaming = fopen( "Highscores.dat", "wb" );
fwrite( data, sizeof(data), 1 , streaming); 
// ...
```

Comment: I read up to _"In my program everything works perfectly!"_

Comment: Well I mean it does, I just want to use a string instead of two ints. It makes it more compact code. :)

Comment: Please post more compact code here

Comment: That is honestly all the code you need? For example the string value would be 0:12, and I want it in the file. And that the code to input it in the file. You don't need more code really..

Comment: Much better thanks :)

Comment: (A complete minimal testcase would still be better)

Comment: @BryanTheCoder Okay: Do you have a string which has the information formatted already? You just want to write the time to the file, correct?

Comment: @Cinch, Yes! The string is already formatted. The string already has a 0 if the seconds are lower than ten. Example: 0:02, and it is formatted if seconds is above ten. Example: 0:12. I just want to save that string exactly in the file the way it is!

Comment: Alright, I'm going to try and answer your question.

Comment: Is there any reason against using `std::time_t` all the way?

Comment: @luk32, what do you mean?

Comment: Use standard type for time stamps instead of inventing a new one unless there is reason not to?

Comment: I have a in game timer that starts with the game starts, is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to simply just write a C-string or `std::string` to a file using C's `fwrite()` function.

This should be quite easy, given that your C-string is in ASCII-conforming format (no Unicode funny business):

```
//It appears you want to use C-style file I/O
FILE* file = NULL;
fopen("Highscores.dat", "wb");

//std::string has an internal C-string that you can access
std::string str = "01:00";
fwrite(str.c_str(), sizeof(char), sizeof(str.c_str()), file);
//You can also do this with regular C strings if you know the size.
```

We can also choose to try and use C++-style file I/O for cleaner interfaces.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::string str = "00:11";

    std::ofstream file("example.txt");

    if (file.good()) {
        file << str;
        std::cout << "Wrote line to file example.txt.\n";
    }
    file.close();

    //Let's check if we actually wrote the file.
    std::ifstream read("example.txt");
    std::string buffer;

    if (read.good())
        std::cout << "Opened example.txt.\n";
    while(std::getline(read, buffer)) {
        std::cout << buffer;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Additionally, there are data types in `<chrono>` that can prove quite helpful for times like there.

If you want to be able to do this:

```
file << data_struct;
```

then it would make sense for you to create an operator overload for std::ostream.

Comment: Yes, this is the proper way to read/write data. I wrote a different answer which uses structures, but that was just for experiment as explained.

Comment: The only reason why I used a char array[] what because I use the highscore list to go from the highest score, then descend to the lowest. With this method, how can I use the string and put it into the char array?

Comment: @BryanTheCoder Your language is unclear. What do you mean by "list" in C++? `std::vector` or `std::list`? Also, you can probably just copy the internal C-string using a C-string function.

Comment: I write into a text file called Highscore, then when I read it, I read the top scores to the bottom.

Comment: That doesn't really *change* anything. You don't need to use a `char` array in most cases. `std::string` would do fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can experiment with time functions. And reading/writing structures.

The right way however is to use c++ basic file storage instead of dumping binar data.

```
struct highscore
{
    char name[10];
    int n;
    std::time_t dateTime;
};

int main()
{
    int total_seconds = 61;
    char buf[50];
    sprintf(buf, "minutes:seconds=> %02d:%02d", total_seconds / 60, total_seconds % 60);
    cout << buf << endl;

    std::time_t timeNow = std::time(NULL);
    std::tm timeFormat = *std::localtime(&timeNow);
    cout << "Current date/time " << std::put_time(&timeFormat, "%c %Z") << endl;

    highscore data;

    //write data:
    {
        FILE *streaming = fopen("Highscores.dat", "wb");

        strcpy(data.name, "name1");
        data.n = 1;
        data.dateTime = std::time(NULL);
        fwrite(&data, sizeof(data), 1, streaming);

        strcpy(data.name, "name2");
        data.n = 2;
        data.dateTime = std::time(NULL);
        fwrite(&data, sizeof(data), 1, streaming);

        fclose(streaming);
    }

    //read data:
    {
        FILE *streaming = fopen("Highscores.dat", "rb");

        fread(&data, sizeof(data), 1, streaming);
        cout << "reading:\n";
        cout << data.name << endl;
        cout << data.n << endl;
        timeFormat = *std::localtime(&data.dateTime);
        cout << std::put_time(&timeFormat, "%c %Z") << endl;
        cout << endl;

        fread(&data, sizeof(data), 1, streaming);
        cout << "reading:\n";
        cout << data.name << endl;
        cout << data.n << endl;
        timeFormat = *std::localtime(&data.dateTime);
        cout << std::put_time(&timeFormat, "%c %Z") << endl;
        cout << endl;

        fclose(streaming);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you're getting confused with the time thing! I have an in game time, which I start when the game starts. And when the game ends, the timer ends. I don't want the actual real-life time!

Comment: _"you should stop using reading/writing with structures because this method is not portable, it's not scalable, and it is prone to errors."_ Huh?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess I should take that back. However it does apply in this particular case. This is clearly a job for c++ basic file storage. Name array is only 10 bytes long, it can't be expanded without deleting old data. This method is endian-dependant, however I am not sure if that matters anymore these days.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Yes, it still matters. Your solution also doesn't take alignment or padding into consideration. This is generally a poor way to perform serialisation. And I still don't get what you meant about "reading/writing with structures" being somehow bad.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think I wasn't wording this right. I wasn't speaking against structures, but against dumping binary data in that way.